# neo4j RESTCypher filter result

Tags: neo4j

We need to minimize data answer in Cypher NEO4J REST API.

is possile set REST Cypher query to return only data, not paged_traverse, outgoing_relationships, traverse or property and soo...?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I've got result like this:

`"paged_traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
          "outgoing_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/relationships/out",
          "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
          "labels": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/labels",
          "create_relationship": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/relationships",
          "traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/traverse/{returnType}",
          "all_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/relationships/all",
          "all_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
          "property": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/properties/{key}",
          "self": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568",
          "incoming_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/relationships/in",
          "properties": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/properties",
          "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/99568/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
          "data": {
            "station": 1,
            "distance": 0,
            "arrtime": 1438747560,
            "line": "XL121",
            "deptime": 1438747560,
            "rid": 128453,
            "type": "train",
            "id": 104088`

and i need only section "data". Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the header: `accept:application/json;compact=true` some endpoints support that.